# Import package problem in GWT

Tags: eclipse, gwt, package, gwt-designer

I'm developing an app using GWT Eclipse plug-in. (I'm also using GWT Designer but I don't think the problem is here). Previously when I wanted a java application to communicate with a web service I created, I produced the "skeleton" classes from the WSDL url using Sun's wsimport tool. Then I would add the classes generated to a class folder in my Eclipse project. All worked well.

However this doesn't seem to be working with GWT. I have these:

```
VideoTutorialServiceService service = new VideoTutorialServiceService();
VideoTutorialService port = service.getVideoTutorialServicePort();
```

and I have `VideoTutorialServiceService` and `VideoTutorialService` underlined in red, the error saying `videotutorialservice.VideoTutorialServiceService can not be found in source packages. Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly.`

.... I googled about it but I got confused. I'm a beginnier in GWT. How can I resolve this please?

Thanks and regards,
Krt_Malta

Answer (score 3):

The problem probably does come from the GWT Designer. See these discussions on GWT Google groups : [GWT Designer errors in Eclipse](https://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/461a3de012b3ce31) and [Cannot found source in GWT Project](https://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/a332d26c0dbdd3dc?hl=en).

You can ever uninstall GWT Designer plugin ^^  or [change the settings](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/preferences/gwt/preferences_builder.html) :

In `WindowBuilder > GWT > Builder`
Uncheck the `Check for "client" classpath` option

Comment: Wow, that was non-obvious!  Thank you, this really helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the capitalization of the VideoTutorialServiceService enclosing class. If you copied/pasted it verbatim then it's looking for videotutorialservice.VideoTutorialServiceService instead of VideoTutorialService.VideoTutorialServiceService

Answer (score 0):

Are VideoTutorialServiceService etc. wsimport generated files? If yes, then they won't work with GWT.

GWT doesn't support all java classes. It just supports a sub-set that makes sense in the javascript world. Remember that GWT is essentially a java -> javascript compiler, so you can't take any java code and expect it to run properly in javascript.

Comment: I see. Do you have any idea how I can access the web service please? Thanks and regards, Krt_Malta

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem, I have a GWT 2.0 app which I have integrated it with spring-security and hibernate. Before I installed GWT Designer it worked okay. Then after installing it, I had this error on Eclipse `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport can not be found in source packages. Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly.`
Then I tried uninstalling GWT Designer and the error was gone. I don't know if this is a bug with GWT designer because In my eclipse class path, I had added the appropriate jar files.